# How to identify what type of encryption in HTTPS header

Tags: encoding, https

I am trying to write a python script to fetch a URL. The issue is that this URI is behind an authentication layer. When I use chrome developer to see what auth header is posted manually I get the below

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Negotiate 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
Connection:keep-alive
Host:xxx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
```

My question is:

How am I able to determine what type of encoding is used in the Authorization field in the header of this message?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded string. You can recognize such string easily because it can contain only letters, numbers, +, /, and = at the end.

If you decode it, it starts with [NTLMSSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLMSSP).

Comment: Thanks I tried using Base64 encoding in the header and it worked. Now i just need to figure out why I keep getting a bad request response :(